# How to access runtime created combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

1) How to access the combos created by below code and set `combo5.Backcolor = vbgreen` after I click `button1`

2) how to set `combo5.Backcolor` to `vbgreen` after I click on the `combo5`

3) how to add item to combo (ie. `combo.Items.Add`) after the creation of that particular combo

```
Private Sub CreateComboArray(ByVal number As Integer, ByVal container As Control)

    Dim previouscombowidth As Integer = 0
    Dim position As Integer = 7
    Dim combo As ComboBox
    For i As Integer = 0 To number - 1

        combo = New ComboBox()
        combo.Name = "combo" + i.ToString()
        combo.Items.Add(RichTextBox1.Text.Split(" ")(i))
        combo.SelectedIndex = 0
        container.Controls.Add(combo)

        combo.Height = 22
        combo.Width = (5 * combo.SelectedItem.ToString.Length) + 10

        If i > 0 Then 
            position += previouscombowidth + 3 
        End If

        combo.Left = position
        combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.Simple
        previouscombowidth = combo.Width 
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Fish the controls back out of the container by name

Comment: how, exactly? can you please provide a code ? I have no idea how.

Comment: `Dim cbo = TabPageX.Controls("combo5")`

Comment: thanks @Plutonix it works ... and how to get or set data when it's being clicked ? I mean clicked on the certain combobox ?

Comment: `AddHandler combo.Click, AddressOf Me.MouseClick` doesn't work as the answer to my question no 2

Comment: you cannot map the CLICK event of a cbo to the MOUSEClick event of the form(?).  Create a procedure with the correct signature, and use AddHandler with that